# linux: symlink for profile

Tags: linux, profile, bash

I saw some guy using Linux set these symlinks in his `/home` as below:

```
.bashrc -> .profile
.bashrc_profile -> .profile
```

I don't know why he set the profile files like this.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @user2393256   why did he set these files like this. `.bashrc`, `.bashrc_profile`, `profile` have their own jobs. Why did he create symlinks like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.profile is used by the original Bourne shell (sh). The bash shell usually ignores the .profile file and looks for a .bashrc or .bashrc_profile depending on your system. By linking all these files to .profile you ensure that the sh as well as the bash have the same configuration.

Comment: `.bashrc` is used for non-login interactive shells. For login shells, `.profile` is used when neither `.bash_profile` nor `.bash_login` is present.